# Inrush current with capacitors connected to USB in parallel

Tags: capacitor, usb, decoupling-capacitor, pc

I did a project that connected to the PC USB. When the PC is being shut down the Vcc (5 volts) is halted. But I need the voltage source to stay for extra milliseconds after the voltage halt.

For that I used capacitors in parallel (both electrolyte and ceramic) connected between the Vcc of the USB to the GND.

I am afraid that connecting these capacitors without any resistors will cause a spike in the current at the beginning of power-on of the system because the capacitor will be charged in 0 [sec].

Is it safe to rely on the parasitic resistance of the capacitors and the wires and the current limiter of the PC USB?

Comment: Capacitors are hooked directly to power rails all the time.  I guess it depends on how much capacitance and ESR we are talking about.

Comment: @connect I would add a series diode (or ideal diode) too so the PC  doesn't suck power from the cap when shutting down.  You don't need ceramics for this. The PC probably has way more parallel  caps in it than what you are going to add anyways, but you can always connect it to the rail through a small charge resistor if you are worried.

Comment: Just saw a Tokin brand 5.5v 47mF supercap which might be ideal for this. Charge it through a suitable current-limiting resistor from Vcc. After some seconds, it should have enough charge to power the device (through a schottky diode.)

Answer (score 1):

For all of you whom interested my issue, I've decided to connect serial resistor [10Ohm] to the decoupling capacitors. Seemed to work fine after the fix